# Installing Package tydiverse in R

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

Does anyone know how to fix these errors. I installed R in Ubuntu which I have through parallels in my Mac computer. I am tryin to install the tidy verse package, but I get these errors:

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘curl’, ‘openssl’ are not available for package ‘httr’
* removing ‘/home/parallels/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/httr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependency ‘httr’ is not available for package ‘rvest’
* removing ‘/home/parallels/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rvest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status

ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘rvest’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/home/parallels/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: sorry, I meant to write tidyverse and not tydiverse

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? How did you installed R? Please add output of `apt-cache policy r-base` to the question.

Comment: The errors seem written in understandable language. Did you notice how the three errors are related to each other? Are you asking how to install dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R packages are usually compiled on the Linux system.

So we need to install some development tools:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential pkg-config r-base-dev
```

and development Ubuntu packages for compilation of mentioned R packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Then you can run R session and install package to it:

> ```
>  $ R
>  > install.packages('tidyverse')
>  ...
>  * DONE (tidyverse)
> ```

---

Note: this method was tested on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS as you have not specified your Ubuntu version.

Comment: Hello I have Ubuntu 18.04 recently installed. It worked perfectly. Thank you so much :)